# Why is the width of space is getting shorter on bitmaps created with a strings, when adding multiple space continuously?

Tags: android, string, bitmap

Currently I'm trying create bitmap from string for printing purpose.

The Issue is,
Spaces between characters are displaying with same width of a character. But when I add multiple spaces, those are getting shorter.

Bitmap creating function.

```
 private Bitmap getBitmap(String string, int size){

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(700, 30, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    Paint paint = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setTextSize(size);
    canvas.drawText( string, 0, 20, paint);

    return bitmap;
}
```

String generating function

```
StringBuilder tempName = new StringBuilder();
        tempName.append(menuItem.getMenuItemName());
        
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            tempName.append("  ");
        }

        tempName.append(price);

        if (menuItem.getMenuItemArabicName().length() > 1)
            tempName.append(menuItem.getMenuItemArabicName() );
        itemName = tempName.toString();
```

Those appended spaces are getting shorter and mis aligns the prices and names on the bitmap.

I tried using \u00A0 and ' '. But still getting shorter. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Maybe you should set a non proportional font like New Courier.

Comment: try to use  TAB symbol

Comment: Thanks for the advices. But later I found that spaces in bitmaps are shorter than other digits. So I decided to print those as string without converting to bitmaps. Otherwise text alignments will be messed up on dynamic content.